# Android, how to add a LinearLayout to a ViewFlipper, programmatically?

Tags: android, viewflipper

How do I add a LinearLayout to a ViewFlipper, programmatically, in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Create your `LinearLayout`

Step #2: Call `addView()` on the `ViewFlipper`, supplying it the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did realize I coud use addView with a layout 30 seconds after I did ask... ;-) Thanks, however...